# Getting REWARDS pintool to work with ELF

Tags: pintool

I am trying to run a pintool I downloaded from this link:

https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/kim1051/

The associated paper is here:
https://www.utdallas.edu/~zxl111930/file/Rewards_NDSS10.pdf

The tool works fine with the provided example. Nevertheless, when I try running an elf-32 or 64 I get the following error:

```
E:Cannot execute file. System error: Unknown error. File name: ".\hello"
E:Pin is exiting due to fatal error
```

The code I used is a simple C hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -m32 hello.c -o hello
```

I am new to Pin, nevertheless I gathered it acts as it's own binary loader so I'm surprised this did not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like your OS is  missing 32-bit support

Comment: I tried this on a windows 7 image 32-bits (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) Moreover is this really relevant for Pin considering it has it's own binary loader which seems to support both 32 and 64 bit architectures?

Comment: wait, are you trying to run a Linux ELF on Windows? I don't think this is going to work...

Comment: in any case, this seems to be a PIN support issue and not really about RE

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well. Nevertheless the paper states that REWARDS works with ELF as well. However in the downloaded zip the pintool is a dll and the pin version is for windows which is why I am confused.

>  "in any case, this seems to be a PIN support issue and not really about RE" 



Fair enough I'll try asking on intel dev forum